# write to the output csv only matched strings from different columns by a regex in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a dataset with more than a million lines. The columns are also unfortunately not so uniform. The information I'm looking for is, unfortunately, sometimes in different columns. Can I filter out somehow and write only that into the output csv?

The dataset consists of similar strings as:

```
07.11.2016  23:20:37    Request completed in 20 ms. Request from 11.1.1.111 action=GetContent&Reference=311.1.1.111&OutputEncoding=UTF8 (11.1.1.111)
```

What I want to write in the output csv:

```
Date;Request(in ms)   
07.11.2016;20;
07.11.2016;332;
07.11.2016;7292;
07.11.2016;3213;
07.11.2016;435;
```

My regex for the date:

```
(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\.(0[1-9]|1[012])\.(19|20)\d\d
```

My regex for the Request Duration:

```
[\0-9]+[ s]
```

My code:

```
import re
import sys

from glob import glob

with open('output.csv', 'a') as combinedFile:
    combinedFile.write('Date;Request(in ms)\n') # Headers
    for eachFile in glob('*.csv'):
        if eachFile == 'C:/x/x/x/x/*.csv':
            pass
        else:
            count = 0
            for line in open(eachFile, 'r'):
                if count != 0:
                    combinedFile.write(line)
                count = 1
```

I am looking for global solutions, because structured solutions unfortunately do not work. The requested string is sometimes in the 2nd column, sometimes in the 3rd column.

I can not display the dataset here because its a logfile and contains personal information.

**I thank you in advance for your help!**

Comment: are you looking for a data that it happens to be on different columns? the problem is on identifying then or writing?

Comment: Where do you attemt to match the regexp to the lines?

Answer (score 0):

you_data.csv file:

```
07.11.2016  23:20:37    Request completed in 20 ms. Request from 11.1.1.111 action=GetContent&Reference=311.1.1.111&OutputEncoding=UTF8 (11.1.1.111)
07.11.2016  23:20:37    Request completed in 20 ms. Request from 11.1.1.111 action=GetContent&Reference=311.1.1.111&OutputEncoding=UTF8 (11.1.1.111)
07.11.2016  23:20:37    Request completed in 20 ms. Request from 11.1.1.111 action=GetContent&Reference=311.1.1.111&OutputEncoding=UTF8 (11.1.1.111)
07.11.2016  23:20:37    Request completed in 20 ms. Request from 11.1.1.111 action=GetContent&Reference=311.1.1.111&OutputEncoding=UTF8 (11.1.1.111)
07.11.2016  23:20:37    Request completed in 20 ms. Request from 11.1.1.111 action=GetContent&Reference=311.1.1.111&OutputEncoding=UTF8 (11.1.1.111)
07.11.2016  23:20:37    Request completed in 20 ms. Request from 11.1.1.111 action=GetContent&Reference=311.1.1.111&OutputEncoding=UTF8 (11.1.1.111)
07.11.2016  23:20:37    Request completed in 20 ms. Request from 11.1.1.111 action=GetContent&Reference=311.1.1.111&OutputEncoding=UTF8 (11.1.1.111)
07.11.2016  23:20:37    Request completed in 20 ms. Request from 11.1.1.111 action=GetContent&Reference=311.1.1.111&OutputEncoding=UTF8 (11.1.1.111)
07.11.2016  23:20:37    Request completed in 20 ms. Request from 11.1.1.111 action=GetContent&Reference=311.1.1.111&OutputEncoding=UTF8 (11.1.1.111)
07.11.2016  23:20:37    Request completed in 20 ms. Request from 11.1.1.111 action=GetContent&Reference=311.1.1.111&OutputEncoding=UTF8 (11.1.1.111)
07.11.2016  23:20:37    Request completed in 20 ms. Request from 11.1.1.111 action=GetContent&Reference=311.1.1.111&OutputEncoding=UTF8 (11.1.1.111)
07.11.2016  23:20:37    Request completed in 20 ms. Request from 11.1.1.111 action=GetContent&Reference=311.1.1.111&OutputEncoding=UTF8 (11.1.1.111)
07.11.2016  23:20:37    Request completed in 20 ms. Request from 11.1.1.111 action=GetContent&Reference=311.1.1.111&OutputEncoding=UTF8 (11.1.1.111)
07.11.2016  23:20:37    Request completed in 20 ms. Request from 11.1.1.111 action=GetContent&Reference=311.1.1.111&OutputEncoding=UTF8 (11.1.1.111)
07.11.2016  23:20:37    Request completed in 20 ms. Request from 11.1.1.111 action=GetContent&Reference=311.1.1.111&OutputEncoding=UTF8 (11.1.1.111)
07.11.2016  23:20:37    Request completed in 20 ms. Request from 11.1.1.111 action=GetContent&Reference=311.1.1.111&OutputEncoding=UTF8 (11.1.1.111)
07.11.2016  23:20:37    Request completed in 20 ms. Request from 11.1.1.111 action=GetContent&Reference=311.1.1.111&OutputEncoding=UTF8 (11.1.1.111)
```

code:

```
with open('you_data.csv') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        split_line = line.split()
        Date = split_line[0]
        Request = split_line[5]
        print(Date, Request)
```

out:

```
07.11.2016 20
07.11.2016 20
07.11.2016 20
07.11.2016 20
07.11.2016 20
07.11.2016 20
07.11.2016 20
07.11.2016 20
07.11.2016 20
07.11.2016 20
07.11.2016 20
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i have not a text string, i have a multiple csv input.. and the csv read have not a split method..

Comment: i updated my code, and i have no idea why someone vote down my answer and do not leave a comment or answer.

Comment: this would work if the csv was "uniform"... this doesn't make sense to me though: _"The requested string is sometimes in the 2nd column, sometimes in the 3rd column."_

Comment: I have not downvote your answer, I will try your approach, thank you!

Comment: @ Jeanderson Barros Cândido this is so much i can do base on the sample code, maybe the OP can post more fake data with same format.